# Flutterで特定のWidgetをデフォルトでアクティブにする方法

Tags: flutter, dart

項目追加画面を開いた時何もしなくてもテキストボックスを自動的にアクティブにしたいのですが、方法はあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

autoFocusという要素がありました。

```dart
TextFormField(
  autofocus: true,
```